# Cant Ping Website but can access to browser

Tags: vpn, ping

I'am trying to ping onlinejobs.ph
but i can'ping it

> admins-MacBook-Air-6:admin$ ping onlinejobs.ph
>
> PING onlinejobs.ph (184.72.40.136): 56 data bytes
>
> Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
>
> Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
>
> Request timeout for icmp_seq 2

but i can access it to my browser.

what is the possible problem?

Answer (score 4):

The two are totally unrelated.

The server can choose to reply or not to ICMP (ping) packets.  There could also be firewall restrictions at any level that could prevent ICMP packets to pass.

If the website is accessible, it means that there is an HTTP (web) server on the URL's host, which is on port 80 by default and not blocked by any firewall.

Many web servers do not reply to ping to alleviate their load and also as a security measure, even if it actually has a very low impact on security.